# Loading ArcGIS vector and raster layers in R (for ipdw package; Inverse Path Distance Weighting)

Tags: r, csv, arcgis, shapefile, r-raster

I am trying to interpolate landscape influences in the coastal/marine environment by inverse distance weighting while accounting for land barrier, and am excited to find the ipdw package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ipdw/ipdw.pdf). Within ArcGIS, I currently have 1) a cost raster object (.adf file) that sets the study extent and 2) a point object (.csv file with latitude, longitude, and intended metric for interpolation) - and am in the process of trying to make them compatible with R.

Can someone direct me to resources for converting a .csv file to a shapefile that would work within the ipdw package, to be loaded as the spdf (SpatialPointsDataFrame) object?

Does the ArcGIS raster have to be in a certain format to be loaded as the costras (cost raster) object?

I would really appreciate any leads and insights!

Comment: Just to clarify - are you looking to couple `ArcGIS` with `R` because you lack a Geostatistical Analyst license? Because 10.3 - 10.5, and ArcGIS Pro, all have their own implementation of [Inverse Distance Weighting](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/creating-maps-using-inverse-distance-weighted-interpolation.htm) that would probably be easier to get going (or is there another reason - like the implementation in `ArcGIS` doesn't cover what you need?)

Comment: For actually answering your questions: reading the documentation and google will take you far. See this [second Google hit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206903/convert-csv-file-to-shapefile-in-r), searching for "converting csv to SpatialPointsDataFrame". Some experimentation will tell you what format the raster should be in (hint: I imagine whatever format you can get your raster in where you can convert it to a `SpatialPolygons` object will work)

Comment: I was unaware of those ArcGIS functions and will absolutely look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial covers creating an sp `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object from a csv:

https://www.neonscience.org/dc-csv-to-shapefile-r

This tutorial covers loading `raster` files in R and combining with vector objects:

https://www.neonscience.org/dc-crop-extract-raster-data-r